# Как из побочного потока указать основному выполнить что-либо

Tags: c#, winforms

Задача следующая: в побочном потоке происходит сравнение двух папок. Если папки не равны, то мне необходимо указать основному потоку на создание прогресс бара, в котором будет отображаться процесс скачивания. Как это сделать?

Comment: Что у вас бежит в основном потоке? Если у вас WPF- или WinForms-приложение, то возможность доставить сообщение в главный поток есть. Если какой-то другой тип приложения с аналогом цикла сообщений в главном потоке — тоже есть. Если это приложение командной строки, то скорее всего возможности нет.

Comment: Для указания сообщений о прогрессе операции существует `Progress<T>`.

Comment: WinForms приложение, сообщения о прогрессе и его окончании есть и работают) но прогресс бар создается в основном потоке заранее, а мне нужно, чтобы побочный сравнил папки и только тогда, когда они не равны сообщал основному, что нужен прогресс бар, так как будет скачивание

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для ваших целей проще всего, наверное, так.

1. Вы создаёте экземпляр класса [`Progress<double>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193692(v=vs.110).aspx) и передаёте его в фоновый поток при его запуске.
2. Фоновый поток, начав копирование, посылает сообщения о прогрессе копирования в этот экземпляр `Progress<double>`.
3. Основной поток, получив первую нотификацию, создаёт/показывает юзеру прогрессбар, и устанавливает значения из нотификации. Последующие нотификации уходят в уже имеющийся прогрессбар.

При этом сообщения о прогрессе будут автоматически маршаллироваться в главный поток. Важно: экземпляр `Progress<double>` должен быть создан в главном потоке, когда приложение уже запущено и бежит (т. к. он запоминает `SynchronizationContext`).

Выйдет как-то так:

```
bool progressBarShown = false;
var progress = new Progress<double>(v =>
    {
        // это будет выполняться в главном потоке
        if (!progressBarShown)
        {
            ShowProgressBar();
            progressBarShown = true;
        }
        progressBar.Value = v;
    });
Task.Run(() =>
    {
        /* это фоновый поток.
           делаем что надо, используем progress для нотификаций */
    });
```

Comment: Для меня это пока не выглядит проще. Мне бы что-то вроде события: сравнил - не равны, в Main Thred тогда создал ShowDialog и все. Все остальное работает)

Comment: @RiseAgainst: Не-не, так проще концептуально. Лучше сейчас потратить 5 минут и разобраться, чем потом думать об перебрасывании event'ов в другой поток.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, попробую)

Comment: у меня в фоновый поток передается само сравнение

Comment: @RiseAgainst: Набросал примерный код.